# Baking rigid body simulation with python script

Tags: python, baking, rigid-body-simulation

I am working on a script to generate scenes and render them.
Since I want my objects to fall on a plane before rendering, what I want to do is bake the rigid body simulation, go to the last frame and render the scene.

I am baking the simulation like this

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
    generate_scene(i)

    #bake
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_start = 0
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end = 100
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(100)

    render_scene(i)
```

At the end of the process my timeline looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the simulation was only baked about till frame 25.
This of course results in a incorrect render.

How can I bake all the frames and render only when I am sure that the bake is done?

Comment: Have you tried the application handler [object_bake_complete](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.object_bake_complete)?